# Two folders sharing the same volume. What does this mean?

Tags: linux, mount

I am trying to understand mount points and shared volumes in a system. What does the following mean? Could you give links to understanding this if possible?

```
1d% pwd
/company/apps/run/prod
1d% df -h shared
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  sanpr-pov:/vol/prod/run/share
                      1.6T  402G  1.2T  26% /company/run/prod/shared
1d% pwd
/company/execute/prod
1d% df -h shared
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  sanpr-pov:/vol/prod/prod/share
                      1.6T  402G  1.2T  26% /company/execute/prod/shared
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A volume can have multiple mount points.  So, if for example, you do:

```
mount /dev/sda1 dir1
mount /dev/sda1 dir2
```

Then sda1 will be mounted both to dir1 and dir2.  The contents of the directories will be identical.

Comment: Or probably `mount --bind` as well.